# what is the difference between ls | grep *e* and ls | grep e

Tags: linux, shell, grep, ls

When used `ls | grep *e*` gives much lesser result than `ls | grep e`, why is it so. Are they not the same commands. Anybody knows the difference between these commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are `ls | grep *e*` and `ls | grep e` not the same commands?

No, they are different. With

```
$ ls | grep *e*
```

the **command shell** expands the pattern `*e*` to match all files which contain the letter `e` in the current directory. This expanded file list is then passed to the `grep` command:

```
$ ls
Hello.txt  Null.txt  Sample.txt
```

When executing

```
$ ls | grep *e*
```

the actual command will be `ls | grep Hello.txt Sample.txt`

With

```
$ ls | grep e
```

there is no file name expansion and the actual command will be `ls | grep e`.

See also

- [Bash reference manual: 3.5.8 Filename Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html)

If you want to pass the parameter without being expanded, you need to quote it:

```
$ ls | grep "*e*"
```

Then, the command actually will be `ls | grep *e*` (with `"*e*"` being passed as `argv[1]` to the grep command).

Note that the shell expansion is different from a regular expression - the shell matches any string for `*`, while in regular expressions `*` denotes that any number of the previous expression shall occur.

Answer (score 0):

The shell expands `*e*` before executing the command. So if you have files named `beer` and `free`, you end up grepping for `beer` in `free`, and ignoring the input from `ls`.

`*e*` is not a valid regular expression, anyway. `*` means "zero or more of the preceding expression" and there is no preceding expression in the first instance. Properly, `grep` should display an error for this, but doesn't. It ends up matching nothing repeated zero or more times, followed by `e` repeated zero or more times. Because every imaginable input contains zero or more occurrences of `e`, it would end up matching every input line.

But anyhow, as noted above, `grep` would not see this input, because it is intercepted and expanded by the shell. If you want to use `*` literally, you need to quote it.

```
ls | grep '.*e.*'
```

is just a really lame way to say

```
ls | grep 'e'
```

because the leading and trailing wildcards add no value -- `grep` always looks for a match anywhere on each input line.

What you actually want is to use the wildcard matching features of the shell:

```
ls *e*
```

The glob expression `*e*` is not a regular expression, but a glob pattern. It does what you apparently expect.